# I am using Libgdx to build a mobile game. Can someone please show me how set the screen to one size?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

package com.test.game;

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Camera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;


public class Splash implements Screen {

    private Sprite splash;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private float height = 1920;
    private float width = 1080;
    private float aspectratio = width/height;



    @Override
    public void render(float delta){


        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.begin();
        splash.draw(batch);
        batch.end();

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height){

    }

    @Override
    public void show(){
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        Texture splashTexture = new Texture("zeuswallpaperphone1.jpg");
        splash = new Sprite(splashTexture);
        //splash.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        splash.rotate(90);
        splash.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2 - splashTexture.getWidth()/2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2 - splashTexture.getHeight()/2);

    }

    @Override
    public void hide(){

    }

    @Override
    public void pause(){

    }

    @Override
    public void resume(){

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(){

    }

}
```

This is the splash screen of my game. I am trying to get the splash screen image to adjust for different screen sizes. Is there a way that I set the screen to one size? I want to set the screen to a size of 1280 x 720. And also will this keep the touch inputs the same? I do not understand why this is so hard in android. I have searched the internet vigorously trying to find a solution. I am also sorry if this question was already answered in another post. It seems that most answers to this problem are really old. I have not been able to find an answer the the problem that I have. I am looking for any help so please someone help me out. I have tried various methods and nothing seems to be working. Thank you in advance for your help. I hate that stack overflow makes you type a certain amount. There are a few libgdx tutorials out there. So if someone could watch one and get back to me that would be great. I have tried playing with the Viewport and Orthographic camera but when I run the game it will not adjust. On iOS you just set the screen size and you are good to go on all devices. They need that in android studio. Nothing seems to be working.
This is the code I have. Thanks for your help. This is crazy they still want me to type more.

Comment: A passer-by says: "I have tried various methods and nothing seems to be working.", you may list what you have tried, which can make others know that these way are not useful. "I hate that stack overflow makes you type a certain amount.", what do you mean with "certain amount"?

Comment: This sounds to me like you need to get an understanding of the "dip" concept and how android handles different screen sizes. Good explanation: https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/understanding-density-independence-in-android, official site: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support Just setting an image to a specific number of pixels may be done by setting width to `1280px`, but that's very certain not what you want to to, as in screens with higher density it will be small and on low-density screens in wont be fully visible

Comment: *"So if someone could watch one and get back to me that would be great."* Are you literally asking for someone to watch tutorial videos and come back here and type out notes on them for you?

Comment: oops, I typed a little too much.

Comment: Oh goodness I just need help

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a camera and viewport:

```
OrthographicCamera hudCamera = new OrthographicCamera();
Viewport hudViewport = new ScreenViewport(hudCamera);

public void create {
    // Your code
    hudViewport.apply(true);
}

 public void render(float delta){
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(hudCamera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    splash.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
}

public void resize(int width, int height) {
    hudViewport.update(width, height);
    hudViewport.apply(true);
}
```

Make sure you are setting the correct size in your main method.